# Different App Icons based on Bundle ID in Build Phases->Run Script

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, info.plist

I had an idea to have both the App Store version of my application and Development version of my application on my phone. I have accomplished this by changing the bundle ID. However I was curious if there would be a way to write a script to determine what the Bundle ID is, and to change the app icon based on what the ID is. Any ideas on how to go about this? So far I have this script:

```
BUNDLE_ID=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" "${BUILD_ROOT}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}")
NORMAL_ID="com.appName"
if [BUNDLE_ID != NORMAL_ID]; then
    // Set testing app icon
else
    // Use normal app icon
fi
```

Comment: You have 2 different targets? How are you switching the bundle id?

Comment: I decided to go against using 2 different targets. I just manually change the bundleID. I just want the app icon to change automatically, instead of me having to change the image and id manually when I go from development to production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this: http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-have-two-versions-of-the-same-app-on-your-device/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: [Overlaying Application Version on Top of Your Icon](http://www.merowing.info/2013/03/overlaying-application-version-on-top-of-your-icon/).

What he's doing is renaming icon files to `IconXXX_base`, and then running a script on each build to generate final icons.

Answer (score 0):

For the `SHELL` part of it, I think you need a dollar `$` sign and double-quotes `"` for the variables.

```
if [ "$BUNDLE_ID" != "$NORMAL_ID" ]; then
    // Set testing app icon
else
    // Use normal app icon
fi
```